# Can you install SSMS for all users

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ssms

I work production support and often have to use an elevated ID and password to resolve issues. When I try to run SSMS or Visual studio with a user ID other than the one it was installed with it tries to reinstall for the new user. Is there a way to install either one of these programs so that it can be run by any user on my computer without having to reinstall?

Comment: Your operation system is win10?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It seems there was a failed update pending. I went into VS Installer and reran the update and I can now do a run as with no issues. This caused another problem that seems to be known without a solution. That is it now takes forever to open a dtsx file.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you install SSMS for all users

Try to reinstall [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) as **Administrator**(right-click on the SSMS Installer Program and then choose **Run as Administrator**).

**Besides**, you could copy the SSMS startup program from this path

```
‪C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
```

into

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

It is a global Start folder for all users.

**Note** that `ProgramData` is a hidden folder.

You could create a folder called `Microsoft SQL Server Tools 18` if the folder does not exits under the path.

**In my side**, I copied it in into:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server Tools 18
```

**And** then SSMS can be used for all users.

Comment: I have to install it using defendpoint. Getting to the shortcut is not the issue. When i right click on the shortcut and do run as and put in the credentials for the elevated id and pw I have checked out as it starts up it starts to reinstall and cant find InstallShield2012.msi.

Comment: Since I am not familiar with using defendpoint. Please try to use the traditional way, click on the installer with Administrator. Maybe this will avoid the issue.